# Grab string from between 2 words but with the beginning

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to grab a string with `sed`. Let's say I got string `aabbcc` and I want to find what is between `aa` and `cc`. I use `sed` like this:

```
sed -n '/aa/,/cc/p'
```

and it's fine but I want to get something like `aabb` so I want sed to return string between beginning and ending but including beginning.

How can I do that?

**EDIT**

Ok let me be more specific. My file where I look for texts looks like this:

```
aa bbbbbbbbbbbbbb  
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb  
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb  
cc
```

Comment: Is the aabbcc string on one line or is it three lines with aa, bb, cc?

Comment: In this file do you want to grab everything including new lines between `aa` and `cc` ?

Comment: Yes I want to grab everything from aa (including it) with new lines till cc (without it).

Comment: Alright edited my answer, check it now.

Answer (score 1):

Use sed like this:

```
d='aabbcc'
s='aa'
e='cc'
sed "s/^\(${a}.*\)${e}$/\1/" <<< "$d"
aabb
```

**EDIT:** Based on edited question, use this command:

```
sed -n '/aa/,/cc/{/cc/!p;}' file
aa bbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

Comment: well it still looks like it doesn't work for me or I lost myself in this regex because I have there dates times etc...

Comment: It worked for your input data provided. Please provide an input and your actual comment which didn't work for you.

Comment: Ok maybe it's my mistake because let's say aa==cc. I mean aa is a date and cc is a date. In my regex it looks like this sed -n '/^$HOUR:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\},[0-9]\{3\} ERROR/,/[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\},[0-9]\{3\}/{/[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\},[0-9]\{3\}/!p;}' $TEMP_FILE

Answer (score 0):

From the current state of your question I gather this is a possible answer:

```
sed -n 's/\(^.*bb\).*/\1/p'
```

used like this:

```
echo "aabbcc" | sed -n 's/\(^.*bb\).*/\1/p'
```

prints

```
aabb
```

Answer (score 0):

For

> Let's say I got string aabbcc and I want to find what is between aa
>   and cc.

```
echo "aabbcc" | sed -r 's/aa(.*)cc/\1/'
```

Output:

```
bb
```

Comment: Note that the OP states `I want to get something like aabb`

Comment: Yes. It's only for that particular note of his.